# DirectShowLib-2005 easycap USB 2.0 interfacing with sony handycam image capture issue

Tags: c#, video, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I have sony handycam attached to Easycap USB 2.0 and I am using DirectShowLib-2005 for image capturing. The source code of the Capture class is below:

```
    public Capture(int iDeviceNum, int iWidth, int iHeight, short iBPP, Control hControl)
    {
        Pic_Control = hControl;

        DsDevice [] capDevices;

        // Get the collection of video devices
        capDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        if (iDeviceNum + 1 > capDevices.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("No video capture devices found at that index!");
        }

        try
        {
            // Set up the capture graph
            SetupGraph( capDevices[iDeviceNum], iWidth, iHeight, iBPP, hControl);

            // tell the callback to ignore new images
            m_PictureReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }


    private void SetupGraph(DsDevice dev, int iWidth, int iHeight, short iBPP, Control hControl)
    {
        int hr;

        ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;
        IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
        IPin pCaptureOut = null;
        IPin pSampleIn = null;
        IPin pRenderIn = null;

        // Get the graphbuilder object
        m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

        try
        {

            m_rot = new DsROTEntry(m_FilterGraph);

            // add the video input device
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(dev.Mon, null, dev.Name, out capFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            // Find the still pin
            m_pinStill = DsFindPin.ByCategory(capFilter, PinCategory.Still, 0);

            // Didn't find one.  Is there a preview pin?
            if (m_pinStill == null)
            {
                m_pinStill = DsFindPin.ByCategory(capFilter, PinCategory.Preview, 0);
            }

            // Still haven't found one.  Need to put a splitter in so we have
            // one stream to capture the bitmap from, and one to display.  Ok, we
            // don't *have* to do it that way, but we are going to anyway.
            if (m_pinStill == null)
            {
                IPin pRaw = null;
                IPin pSmart = null;

                // There is no still pin
                m_VidControl = null;

                // Add a splitter
                IBaseFilter iSmartTee = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();

                try
                {
                    hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(iSmartTee, "SmartTee");
                    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                    // Find the find the capture pin from the video device and the
                    // input pin for the splitter, and connnect them
                    pRaw = DsFindPin.ByCategory(capFilter, PinCategory.Capture, 0);
                    pSmart = DsFindPin.ByDirection(iSmartTee, PinDirection.Input, 0);

                    hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(pRaw, pSmart);
                    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                    // Now set the capture and still pins (from the splitter)
                    m_pinStill = DsFindPin.ByName(iSmartTee, "Preview");
                    pCaptureOut = DsFindPin.ByName(iSmartTee, "Capture");

                    // If any of the default config items are set, perform the config
                    // on the actual video device (rather than the splitter)
                    if (iHeight + iWidth + iBPP > 0)
                    {
                        SetConfigParms(pRaw, iWidth, iHeight, iBPP);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (pRaw != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pRaw);
                    }
                    if (pRaw != pSmart)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pSmart);
                    }
                    if (pRaw != iSmartTee)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(iSmartTee);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Get a control pointer (used in Click())
                m_VidControl = capFilter as IAMVideoControl;

                pCaptureOut = DsFindPin.ByCategory(capFilter, PinCategory.Capture, 0);

                // If any of the default config items are set
                if (iHeight + iWidth + iBPP > 0)
                {
                    SetConfigParms(m_pinStill, iWidth, iHeight, iBPP);
                }
            }

            // Get the SampleGrabber interface
            sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;

            // Configure the sample grabber
            IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
            ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);
            pSampleIn = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            // Get the default video renderer
            IBaseFilter pRenderer = new VideoRendererDefault() as IBaseFilter;
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(pRenderer, "Renderer");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            pRenderIn = DsFindPin.ByDirection(pRenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            // Add the sample grabber to the graph
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter( baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber" );
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            if (m_VidControl == null)
            {
                // Connect the Still pin to the sample grabber
                hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(m_pinStill, pSampleIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                // Connect the capture pin to the renderer
                hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(pCaptureOut, pRenderIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
            }
            else
            {
                // Connect the capture pin to the renderer
                hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(pCaptureOut, pRenderIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                // Connect the Still pin to the sample grabber
                hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(m_pinStill, pSampleIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
            }

            // Learn the video properties
            SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);
            ConfigVideoWindow(hControl);

            // Start the graph
            IMediaControl mediaCtrl = m_FilterGraph as IMediaControl;
            hr = mediaCtrl.Run();
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sampGrabber != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampGrabber);
                sampGrabber = null;
            }
            if (pCaptureOut != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pCaptureOut);
                pCaptureOut = null;
            }
            if (pRenderIn != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pRenderIn);
                pRenderIn = null;
            }
            if (pSampleIn != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pSampleIn);
                pSampleIn = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveSizeInfo(ISampleGrabber sampGrabber)
    {
        int hr;

        // Get the media type from the SampleGrabber
        AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();

        hr = sampGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType( media );
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        if( (media.formatType != FormatType.VideoInfo) || (media.formatPtr == IntPtr.Zero) )
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException( "Unknown Grabber Media Format" );
        }

        // Grab the size info
        VideoInfoHeader videoInfoHeader = (VideoInfoHeader) Marshal.PtrToStructure( media.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader) );
        m_videoWidth = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Width;
        m_videoHeight = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Height;
        m_stride = m_videoWidth * (videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.BitCount / 8);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        media = null;
    }


    private void ConfigVideoWindow(Control hControl)
    {
        int hr;

        IVideoWindow ivw = m_FilterGraph as IVideoWindow;

        // Set the parent
        hr = ivw.put_Owner(hControl.Handle);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        // Turn off captions, etc
        hr = ivw.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipChildren | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        // Yes, make it visible
        hr = ivw.put_Visible( OABool.True );
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        // Move to upper left corner
        Rectangle rc = hControl.ClientRectangle;
        hr = ivw.SetWindowPosition( 0, 0, rc.Right, rc.Bottom );
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
    }

    private void ConfigureSampleGrabber(ISampleGrabber sampGrabber)
    {
        int hr;
        AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();

        // Set the media type to Video/RBG24
        media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        media.subType = MediaSubType.RGB24;
        media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        hr = sampGrabber.SetMediaType( media );
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        media = null;

        // Configure the samplegrabber
        hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback( this, 1 );
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
    }


    private void SetConfigParms(IPin pStill, int iWidth, int iHeight, short iBPP)
    {
        int hr;
        AMMediaType media;
        VideoInfoHeader v;

        IAMStreamConfig videoStreamConfig = pStill as IAMStreamConfig;

        // Get the existing format block
        hr = videoStreamConfig.GetFormat(out media);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        try
        {
            // copy out the videoinfoheader
            v = new VideoInfoHeader();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure( media.formatPtr, v );

            // if overriding the width, set the width
            if (iWidth > 0)
            {
                v.BmiHeader.Width = iWidth;
            }

            // if overriding the Height, set the Height
            if (iHeight > 0)
            {
                v.BmiHeader.Height = iHeight;
            }

            // if overriding the bits per pixel
            if (iBPP > 0)
            {
                v.BmiHeader.BitCount = iBPP;
            }

            // Copy the media structure back
            Marshal.StructureToPtr( v, media.formatPtr, false );

            // Set the new format
            hr = videoStreamConfig.SetFormat( media );
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
        }
        finally
        {
            DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
            media = null;
        }
    }
```

The code is throwing an exception at the line:
hr = mediaCtrl.Run();

The value of hr returned is -2147023729

Because of this image capturing is not working. Can someone please help me fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The code is [`0x8007048F` `ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED` "The device is not connected."](http://alax.info/blog/1383). No capture is going to take place if/when device is not connected, isn't it? The error is likely to be forwarded from one of the filters, esp. capture filter, so your troubleshooting should start with inspecting topology of your capture filter graph.